# Why union-find algorithm runs in amortized time?

Tags: algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

I have an exercise that is stated:

> What's amortized time of series on $n$ operations where all union
>   operations precede find operations?

I know it should be $n$ for series but I struggle with proving that.

Maybe someone fluent with proofs could help me?

Answer (score 1):

**A bungling proof**

> A series of $n$ `union` operations (or `find` ones) on $m$ elements run in $O(n\;\alpha(m))$, where $\alpha$ is the inverse Ackermann function.

To get a sense of its growth, observe that

$$\alpha(m) = \begin{cases}
0, & 0\le m \le 2,\\
1, & m = 3,\\
2, & 4 \le m \le 7\\
3, & 8 \le m \le 2047\\
4, & 2048 \le m \le 16^{512} \gg 10^{80}\\
5, & 16^{512} \le m \le \dots
\end{cases}$$

You can see that Inverse Ackermann function verifies $0 \leq \alpha(m) \leq 4$ for *all* practise inputs of size $m$ (note that $10^{80}$ is the estimated number of atoms of the universe), so it is considered that
$$\alpha(m) \subset O(1)$$
This results implies that a series of $n$ `union` operations on $m$ elements run in $O(n)$ time in an average case.

**A complete proof**

Wait until someone smarter than me posts `;)`. Alternatively, you've got a complete proof in

> Thomas H. CORMEN; Charles E. LEISERSON; Ronald
>   L. RIVEST; Clifford STEIN (2009).
>   *Introduction
>   to  Algorithms*. Third Edition.

See Chapter 21 - Data Structures for Disjoint Sets,  Section 21.4 - Analysis of union by rank with path compression (pages 573-582).

Comment: I'm familiar with proof for nlog*(m) but I think this exercise is about proving the special case where all unions are before finds. This should limit possibilities somehow and allow to prove by accounting method that it's O(n) theoretically.